# Service Method Getting a 404 Not Found Error

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf

I have a Web API project with a WCF in it. In my code I have a method called CreatePerson which adds a user inputted information to a SQL database. The issue I'm having is that once I load the .aspx page and hit my "Add Person" button, which then invokes an angular function which is SUPPOSED to send that data to the CreatePerson method via an $http.post, I get a 404 error in the dev tools, saying that it cannot find that specified address.

Here is my code:

family1.aspx:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Inherits="WebApplication6.family1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<h2>Family App</h2>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.js"></script>


    </head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="familyCtrl">

<form ng-submit="addPerson()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstNameInput" size="20" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastNameInput" size="20" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="number" ng-model="ageInput" size="20" placeholder="Age" />
    <!--<input type ="number" ng-model="monthInput" stye=20 placeholder="Month" />/
    <input type ="number" ng-model="dayInput" stye=20 placeholder="Day" />/
    <input type ="number" ng-model="yearInput" stye=20 placeholder="Year" />-->
    <input type="submit" value="Add New Person">
</form> 

<br>

<table style ="width:50%">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Age</td><td>Remove</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <div ng-repeat="per in family"><span ng-bind="per.FirstName"></span>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="per.LastName"></span></div>
             </td>

               <td> <div ng-repeat="per in family"><span ng-bind="per.Age"></span></div>

                </td>

                <td><div ng-repeat="per in family"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="per.IsActive" ></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<p><button ng-click="remove()">Remove marked</button></p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('familyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.family = [];

    var parameters = {FirstName : "Joseph", LastName :"Neathery", Age : 19};




    $scope.addPerson = function () {
        $scope.family.push({ FirstName: $scope.firstNameInput, LastName: $scope.lastNameInput, Age: $scope.ageInput, IsActive: false });
        $http.post('/Service1/CreatePerson', parameters);
    }
    $scope.remove = function () {
        var oldFamily = $scope.family;
        $scope.family = [];
        angular.forEach(oldFamily, function (per) {
            if ((!per.IsActive))
                $scope.family.push(per);

        });
    };
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

IService.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication6
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService     
    {

        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/Service1/CreatePerson", Method ="POST", RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        void CreatePerson(Person p);

    }
}
```

Service1.svc.cs:

```
 public class Service1 : IService
    {

        public void CreatePerson(Person p)
        {

            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FamilyAppConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.Person__Create", conn);
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FirstName", p.FirstName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("LastName", p.LastName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Age", p.Age));

                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FamilyAppConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=JN-LAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FamilyApp;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>

      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
  <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers></system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebApplication6.EndPointBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="WrappedRequest" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpBinding" transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WebApplication6.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:61512/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication6.EndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication6.IService"
          bindingConfiguration="HttpBinding" />
        <endpoint
                  address="/CreatePerson  "
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication6.EndPointBehavior"
                  contract="WebApplication6.IService"
        />
        <endpoint
           address="mex"
           binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange"
        />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You are trying to access a WCF service as if it's a WEB API method and that's the issue here. You can't access like that unless you create a proxy and access via it.

Comment: Very new to WCF services. Could you possibly elaborate further with an example of where and how to do this?

Comment: Search google for creating WEB API method and will get millions of example.